# GNOME extension dash-to-panel shows error message

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

I am using Ubuntu 19.10, it runs GNOME 3.34.1. I have installed the extension "Dash-to-panel" yesterday. It was just fine, no error message, and the top panel was correct. But this morning I now have an "ERROR" in the extension on my "Installed Extensions" and the top panel is messed up.

How can I fix this issue?

I did send a bug message to the author of this extension, plus posted my comment on the extension site.

Answer (score 13):

Later in Ask Ubuntu, I saw where someone had the same problem.

I pressed <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, entered `r`, and then pressed <kbd>enter</kbd> & my issue is now fixed.

Comment: how does one close this question?

Comment: Please [see this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for how to accept an answer.

Comment: Are you sure it's actually "ALT+r"? Not "ALT+F2", then "r", and then "Enter"?

Comment: @user18432 you can simply delete your own question if you come to realize it won't be relevant for future users. Did you install the extension from the Gnome Extensions website? If yes, then remove and install from the package manager. That is a version that will be more stable in your current Ubuntu version.

Comment: +1 Worked perfectly on 20.04, Gnome 3.36.4.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but after a lot of googling I managed to find a solution:

1. First install the "GNOME shell integration" to your chrome browser.
2. Once installed click on the "GNOME shell integration" extension in chrome.
   It should take you to "extensions.gnome.org"
3. Once there search for "dash-to-dock" extension by michelle_g
   Click on it and install the extension to your computer
4. When its done installing, the favorites bar should appear.
   To verify that the extension has been installed go to the extensions
   application on your OS and under manually installed you should find the
   newly installed Dash to Dock extension.

Answer (score 0):

Same situation in my case. You can visit [this webpage](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1160/dash-to-panel/), and  click the top-right green button to 'update' it to version 44. It seems version 45-1 in the repo has a problem with current gnome-shell 40.5. Just remember by dong this you are to run a manually installed extension located in *$HOME/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/*, not in */usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/*.