# Can't disable Ubuntu Dock

Tags: gnome, dock, gnome-tweaks

This is driving me crazy. I have disabled the Ubuntu Dock extension and even tried to uninstall it but the Dock is still there! And there is no other Dock extension installed. How do I get rid of it?

**EDIT:** Well, it turned out that disabling it in extensions app (not gnome tweak tool) worked. Then killing the Gnome shell.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uc4Vj.png)

Comment: don't kill, just `reload` it should be enough. Alt+F2 and type `r` , then press "Enter". Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1200635/gnome-extension-dash-to-panel-shows-error-message

Comment: @pLumo Alt+F2 and r is not available any more in newer Ubuntu versions and was removed